# PostgreSQL: Querying a table based on the existence of a dynamic field in an object nested inside another object which is in an array of objects

Tags: json, postgresql, psql, jsonb

In a table `items`, I have a jsonb column called `users`. The JSON structure of `users` follows the following example:

```
[
    {
        "required": 1,
        "agents": {
            "user1": "A",
            "user2": "P",
            "user3": "A"
        }
    },
    {
        "required": 3,
        "agents": {
            "user1": "P",
            "user4": "P",
            "user5": "P"
        }
    }
]
```

Note that the table `items` has many fields, but for the sake of simplicity, we can consider that it has only an `item_id` and a `users` field. And all answers I saw here on SO provide queries for elements of objects directly inside an array.

I also wish I could rewrite the object's structure in a better way, but it's not my decision in this case :D.

I'm new to JSON queries in postgres, so I tried to write a few queries without success.

**Question:**
I'm trying to find a query, that can return all `items` that have a key 'user4' inside the agents sub-object of any element in the array. Any suggestions?

Comment: Something like `SELECT * FROM items WHERE (JSON_ARRAY_ELEMENTS(users)->'agents'->>'user4') IS NOT NULL`? Though that would also pick up if `user4` was there but its value was `null`.

Comment: Something like that, but if I use the query you provided, I get an error: `function json_array_elements(jsonb) does not exist`. The function json_array_elements doesn't accept that argument type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the function `jsonb_array_elements()` and the `?` operator:

```
select i.*
from items i
cross join jsonb_array_elements(users)
where value->'agents' ? 'user4'
```

See [JSON Functions and Operators.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-json.html)